# Relative layout background on hold

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to set a relative layouts background color when the user holds it only and then revert back after they let off but can't seem to get it to respond.

My xml for my activity looks as so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:background="@drawable/preferencesbg"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true">
```

I did as I have seen elsewhere and set the background to a drawable

preferencesbg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/darkblue" />


    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

But for whatever reason still can't get it to work.

This is some java I tried, but ended up deleting it, now there is nothing but the onCreate method in the activity,

```
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.one);

        rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rl.setBackgroundColor(R.color.darkblack);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you do the color change in the onClickListener? Paste the java code

Comment: I posted some that I tried but ended up removing because It would set the wrong color? Not sure why, I wanted it to set black (#000) but it set some weird gray color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if your RelativeLayout contains no other elements, set `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content` so that the layout height is more than 0dp.

Then change your items to:

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/darkblue" />
```

Then your background should change the way you want without writing any Java code.

Comment: wow, thanks I don't know why I was having such a hard time with that